# Desactivar caché SÓLO en el header

Tags: php, wordpress, cache

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en WordPress 4.9.6 y utilizo el plugin WP Super Caché para cachear el sitio web.

El problema es que en el header muestro un mensaje u otro dependiendo del usuario que ha iniciado sesión. Este mensaje se cachea también y por tanto se muestra lo que no debe mostrarse.

```
<ul id="user-menu" class="menu">
    <?php if ($up->current_user->ID == 0) : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($up->signup_page) ?>">Registro</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($up->profile_page) ?>">Inicio de sesión</a></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($up->profile_page) ?>">Hola, <?= $up->current_user_data->first_name ?></a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

¿Alguna idea? ¿Alguna función escrita a mano que me permita hacer esto?

Comment: Nose si te pase lo mismo que a mi .. lo primero que tuve que hacer es que andes de validar el usuario... mando a borrar toda la cache... una vez cn ello en base al tipo de usuario se creara la respectiva cache...

Comment: cómo mandas a borrar toda la caché en código? Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: te recomiendo revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037249/how-to-clear-browser-cache-with-php

Comment: ya lo había leído, he mirado todo... pero eso es para no cachear una página entera, yo necesito descachear sólo una parte de la página.

Answer (score 0):

En mi modesta opinión y por lo que explicas, ese código debes reescribirlo, y solo lanzarlo cuando el usuario este logueado, y de esa manera no se cacheará, pienso:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){
     echo '<li><a href="'. echo get_permalink($up->profile_page).'">Hola, 
     '.$up->current_user_data->first_name.'</a></li>';
}
```

Tengo mis dudas respecto al scope de las variables tal como las mencionas no sé si funcionarían.